# Final Cut - unable to set clip duration to a fraction of a second

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, final-cut-pro

When I select a clip in Final Cut Pro, and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> to edit the duration, I can enter `100` then enter and it will make the clip 1:00 second long. However if I try to do `30`, it still rounds it up to 1:00 second long. Why won't it let me make a clip appear for a fraction of a second?

Comment: What is the frame rate of the sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:30 is 1s at 30fps, so FCPX rounds it to 1s. For half a second on a 30fps project, enter :15.